# Dropping foreign key using variable as name

Tags: mysql, sql

I use the following:

```
DECLARE @ConstraintName varchar(255);
SELECT @ConstraintName = CONSTRAINT_NAME 
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable' 
   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'TheColumn';

alter table TheTable drop constraint @ConstraintName;
```

But, it has incorrect syntax near @ConstraintName. It might be a small thing but I can't figure it out. What should I change so the constraint will be dropped?

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6709e/3

Comment: Isn"t it SELECT INTO @ConstraintName ... ???

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond That gives me 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO''.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @constraintName VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @runString VARCHAR(2000);

select @constraintName = CONSTRAINT_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'TheColumn';


SET @runString = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE TheTable DROP CONSTRAINT ', @constraintName);
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @runString ;
EXECUTE stm1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Comment: `add constraint`, but `drop foreign key`

Comment: `concat`, not `+`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @ConstraintName VARCHAR(255);
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME 
INTO @ConstraintName 
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable' 
   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'TheColumn';

alter table TheTable drop constraint @ConstraintName;
```

Or :

```
DECLARE @ConstraintName VARCHAR(255);
SELECT @ConstraintName:=CONSTRAINT_NAME 
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable' 
   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'TheColumn';

alter table TheTable drop constraint @ConstraintName;
```

Comment: They didn't work. The first has incorrect syntax near @ConstraintName, the second has incorrect syntax near ':'.

Comment: @Joetjah can you create a SQLFiddle so we can have some test by ourselves? http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @Joetjah plus, where are you testing your request? command line, PhpMyAdmin, workbench, ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME INTO @ConstraintName 
FROM 
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE 
   TABLE_NAME = 'TheTable' 
   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'TheColumn';

SET @queryStr = CONCAT('alter table TheTable drop constraint ', @ConstraintName);
PREPARE qry from @queryStr;
EXECUTE qry;
```

For more information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/execute.html